# javascript setInterval(tick(), 1000)

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

The following is my code, it will call tick(a function which will print something on console) per second

```
function tick() {
    console.log("djfiah");
}
windowa.onload(){
    var id = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}
```

If the code become

```
var id = setInterval(tick(), 1000);
```

Why the tick will be called only once?

Comment: Because `()` will invoke the function immediately. Since, nothing is returned from `tick()`, `undefined` is returned which is not function so `setInterval` is not working.

Comment: Thank you! I get it